# How do I test Server Sent Event API responses in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, server-sent-events

I'm currently using the following code to subscribe to a Server Side Event API:

```
import requests
import sseclient
import json
import pprint

def get_recent_change():
    url = 'https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange'
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    client = sseclient.SSEClient(response)
    for event in client.events():
        pprint.pprint(json.loads(event.data))
    return

get_recent_change()
```

Which works! Outputting the following data stream (only one entry shown):

```
{'bot': True,
 'comment': 'fixing url',
 'id': 998191574,
 'length': {'new': 664, 'old': 662},
 'meta': {'domain': 'commons.wikimedia.org',
          'dt': '2017-11-07T07:24:14+00:00',
          'id': 'a8e00e00-c38c-11e7-b9f1-b083fecef9b0',
          'offset': 526240012,
          'partition': 0,
          'request_id': 'e9052543-9df8-4ff6-a94e-06629f9aef0e',
          'schema_uri': 'mediawiki/recentchange/1',
          'topic': 'eqiad.mediawiki.recentchange',
          'uri': 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:St_Cuthbert%27s_High_School_-_geograph.org.uk_-_71872.jpg'},
 'minor': True,
 'namespace': 6,
 'parsedcomment': 'fixing url',
 'patrolled': True,
 'revision': {'new': 266424348, 'old': 155939348},
 'server_name': 'commons.wikimedia.org',
 'server_script_path': '/w',
 'server_url': 'https://commons.wikimedia.org',
 'timestamp': 1510039454,
 'title': "File:St Cuthbert's High School - geograph.org.uk - 71872.jpg",
 'type': 'edit',
 'user': 'HiW-Bot',
 'wiki': 'commonswiki'}
```

How do I write a test for get_recent_change()? Everything I try hangs because the stream is never closed...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out of this manner. I know that is not the best solution but it works!!.
In this case, I just only download the first 50 payloads
Here my code:

```
def get_recent_change(self) -> list:
    # se inicializa un socket
    r = requests.session()
    # se establece la conexión
    responds = r.get(self.__url, stream=True)
    try:
        # se capturan los eventos
        client = sseclient.SSEClient(responds)
        print('Connection established')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    # limitador del stram
    cont = 0
    payloads = []
    try:
        print('Downloading info')
        for event in client.events():
            #el primer evento no sirve
            if cont==0:
                pass
            # captura muchos payloads en un solo evento, tocó separarlos
            for st in event.data.split('\n'):
                # Progress bar of the poor
                print('-', end='',flush=True)
                #se guardan en una lista
                payloads.append(json.loads(st))
            if cont >= 50:
                break
            cont +=1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return payloads
```